# Storing user and application core data differently

Tags: ios, core-data, app-update

In my IOS app, I store two types of data in CoreData. One type is user generated, the other type is a pregenerated database. Currently this is all in the same store, which goes into the documents folder. But this is not a good approach, so I will split into 2 separate stores.

There are two problems:

1. The pregenerated database should not be backed up by iCloud.
2. When an update of the app is provided, the user data should be kept, but the pregenerated database should be overwritten. (The pregenerated database will have updated content, even if the data model is unchanged.)

For problem 1, I can either put the pregenerated database store in the cache directory, or keep it in the documents directory flagged for skipping backup. As the cache directory can be emptied any time, using the documents folder without backup seems better. However, does that solve problem 2? That is, will the pregenerated database be overwritten after an update?

If not, are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep pregenerated rated database in document folder and flag it for skipping backup in iCloud. However you have to write some script to overwrite the data Or on update you can delete your pregenerated store completely and create it again with updated data.

Comment: Thanks @sanjana. Do you mean a script like on http://themainthread.com/blog/2014/03/replacing-a-core-data-store.html ? How does the program know it is running the first time after an update?

Comment: "How does the program know it is running the first time after an update?" I copied the bundle version to [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults].

Comment: Can store one more boolean flag in userdefault isFirstTime, set/reset flag according to current and previously stored bundle version.